# Spring: Can't override properties with @ConfigurationProperties for test

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-properties, configurationproperties

I'm trying to configure property for test, using @ConfigurationProperties.

My config-class with properties:

```
 @Data
 @Configuration
 @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "data")
 public class TestFileSettings {
     private String dockerMountPath;
}
```

Property-file "application-test.properties" contains:

```
data.docker_mount_path=testMountHostDirectory/
```

And test-class:

```
  @ActiveProfiles("test")
  @TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
  @EnableConfigurationProperties(value = {TestFileSettings.class})
  @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
  @SpringBootTest()
  public class PropertyAcessTest {
       @Autowired
       private TestFileSettings testFileSettings;

       @Test()
       public void testPropertyAcess() {        
       String getDockerMountPath = testFileSettings.getDockerMountPath();
       assertEquals("testMountHostDirectory/", getDockerMountPath)
     {
```

But I get the following error:

```
  error: cannot find symbol
    String getDockerMountPath = testFileSettings.getDockerMountPath();
                                                ^
 symbol:   method getDockerMountPath()
 location: variable testFileSettings of type TestFileSettings
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: looks like your lombok is not enabled for test compile time

Comment: Yep, apart from the prior comment it seems that the title of this question is slightly misleading as this one seems to be an issue at compile time. Spring Boot hasn't got the chance yet to apply any properties. ;-)

Comment: Deadpool, yes, its lombok jokes!)